# Multiple Indirection C++ Integer types

Tags: c++

im trying to remove an element from my array and was wondering if I could be ultra-efficeint using multiple indirection with my int ptrs.

The maxSize for my fixed-array lies within my hashTable->maxSize

I need to be able to refer to my hashTable's private member maxSize 
only as a reference. The varaible: &maxSize, holds nothing, it is NULL.
What has my fixed-size is hashTable->maxSize;

```
bool hashmap::remove(char const * const symbol)
{
int **previous_index = &maxSize;
int  *current_index  = *previous_index;

while ( current_index && 
             strcmp( symbol, hashTable[*current_index].m_symbol ) != 0 ) 
{
    previous_index = &current_index + 1;
    current_index  = *previous_index;
}
return true;
}
```

I've been trying to get it to compile with a *maxSize int single ptr varaible.
But i have a lot of code and its all affected. hehe.

Comment: Mr. Andre was helpful today. I even check marked his reply as a solution.

Comment: is there a question here ? .. I dont get it ..

Comment: my hashTable->maxSize holds a integer value of 11, as my fixed-size of an array.

the varaible maxSize as a reference holds nothing and is null.

Is their a way to write hashTable->maxSize as a reference?

Comment: Your const char *const doesn't need another const. `const char *` is sufficient.

Comment: State your intentions, unless you make clear what you really want to achieve, you will never get proper answers. The fact that only once you got an usable answer may have more to do with how you ask than what they answer. More often than not, when the question is clearly stated you will get an answer within a couple of minutes (unless it is a real technical one that needs rechecking with the standard or complex tests, but that is not your case here)

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a hashmap, I would recommend that you directly use std::tr1::unordered_map, accepted into the TR1 of the C++ standard back in 2003 and implemented in many compilers. It will become std::unordered_map within the next standard (C++0x).

Now, if you want criticism on the code: do not use C style strings, prefer std::string. If your code is going to unconditionally return true, then consider that maybe your code should not return at all. Comment your algorithm (not each line): *Search backwards until I find a match and remove it. Removal is performed ...* that will help others detect where your code does not comply with your intentions. I am yet to understand how you are trying to iterate the array. The code probably differs from your intentions in more than one place.

If you are really implementing a hashmap then you should use the hash algorithm to find the element to remove (if it does exist). It does not make sense building a complex system that has O(1) search time to linearly search.

Answer (score 1):

A hashmap could easily utilise a `std::map<std::string, list<T *>>` to save a lot of time. Utilising a private map, your remove-symbol function would be as simple as:

```
bool hashmap::remove (const char *key)
{
    m_map.remove(key);
}
```

Comment: What i've written is nearly complete

Comment: It's a smarter, more efficient way. Use STL, don't fight it.

Comment: Or use other libraries like boost (which most likely would contain a hash map implementation).

Comment: Im looking for something along the lines of, "Well mr. newbie, even if you access hashTable->maxSize it still would do 'such and such'..
lol, ya know?

Comment: I can't understand the code you posted above. its full of strange pointers you don't need, and the implementation looks strange for what you want to do.